# Add % sign in Data Labels Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a simple chart in Google Sheets. Currently, the data labels are just numbers. I want to append a % sign infront of each value. How can I do so?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wyubPje-e-bF2UJjwjMGk2NOKbi5_5G9FHP4FMGpSMQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I am not proficient in google sheet, but I think it should have similar functions：

Enter a similar formula next to each cell: ="%"&A2

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VBA macro for this:

```
Sub AppendPercent()
  Dim objCell as Range
  For Each objCell in Selection
    If objCell.Value <> "" Then objCell.Value = objCell.Value & "%"
  Next
End Sub
```

Now before running this macro, select all the cells where percent is needed to be appended. Then click <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications and then in Insert > Module paste the code. Then hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run macro.

Comment: Google Sheets don't have VBA.

Comment: @harrymc but the question has been tagged Microsoft-excel, I have written  in excel perspective.